# iPhone: MKAnnotation show popup?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

I have a MKMapView that has a pin than when pressed shows the annotation's title and subtitle.

Is there a way in code to have this text shown automatically so the user does not need to click it?

If I have many pins, can they all appear as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the [selectAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/selectAnnotation:animated:) message on *MKMapView*:

```
- (void)selectAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation animated:(BOOL)animated
```

> Selects the specified annotation and
>   displays a callout view for it.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: The docs say this is not to be used , You should not call this method directly. An MKMapView object calls this method in response to user interactions with the annotation.

Comment: That's a good point - sorry I missed the discussion item in the doc. I'm not sure if it is app store rejection worthy but I'm not aware of another way to do this. Curious from an HID standpoint if you attempting to trigger the overlay in response to another user action or if you are just trying to make a bunch Titles appear over multiple markers concurrently.

Comment: Yes, we have 1 to 3 pins and want all of them to appear each time the map appears.

Answer (score 0):

If your MKMapView is called mapView and your MKAnnotation is called myAnnotation then this will work:

```
[mapView selectAnnotation:myAnnotation animated:YES];
```